# Regarding free function in c

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

May I know that if I free something in C programming language and I declare it as pointer before, it would just free out the memory but the pointer is still there or the pointer data type will also be destroyed as the code below. Also, may I know that if I want to free up my memory in this situation, why would I use free(list) in the end instead of using free(tmp)? Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    int *list = malloc(3 *sizeof(int));
    if (list==NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    list[0] = 1;
    list[1] = 2;
    list[2] = 3;

    int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    if (tmp==NULL){
        free(list);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        tmp[i] = list[i];
    }

    tmp[3] = 4;

    free(list);

    list = tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%i\n", list[i]);
    }

    free(list);
}
```

Comment: `why would I use free(list) in the end instead of using free(tmp)` - after the `list = tmp;` line the two are identical.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError alright, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these declarations

```
int *list = malloc(3 *sizeof(int));

int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

you declared two pointers `list` and `tmp` that has automatic storage duration. The pointers themselves point to dynamically allocated arrays that (the memory occupied by the arrays) should be freed using the function `free` to avoid memory leaks.

After calling the function free the pointers will have invalid values.

What the program is doing is at first it allocated dynamically an integer array with three elements and the address of the allocated memory is assigned to the pointer list.

```
int *list = malloc(3 *sizeof(int));
```

Then the program tries to reallocate the array by means at first of allocating dynamically a new array with four elements

```
int *tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

If the allocation was successful then the old array is freed

```
free(list);
```

and the address of the new array is assigned again to the pointer list.

```
list = tmp;
```

That is now the two pointers `list` and `tmp` point to the same dynamically allocated array. You can use either pointer to free the allocated memory but logically it is better to use the pointer list because the program simulates reallocation an array initially pointed to by the pointer `list`.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanation and I can now figure it out!

Answer (score 4):

Calling `free` does not affect the pointer or its contents, just what the pointer pointed to.  But the value in that pointer should no longer be considered valid.

The part about your specific use of `free` was addressed in the comments.

Comment: thank you very much I am now clear about what is going on!